# Query behaves strange with php while working in phpmyadmin and mysql console.

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table like below:

targets :

```
target_id | territory_id | emp_id_tar | target_week            | target |
15        | 22           | 61         | 2013-10-20/2013-10-26  | 50000  |
17        | 22           | 63         | 2013-10-20/2013-10-26  | 2000   |
18        | 22           | 64         | 2013-10-20/2013-10-26  | 150000 |
```

As you can see there is a target_week column where within these days an employee should accomplish that much of amount.

Now I tried with the query below:

```
SELECT * 
FROM targets
WHERE emp_id_tar =61
AND MONTH( SUBSTRING_INDEX( target_week,  '/', 1 ) ) = MONTH( CURRENT_DATE( ) ) 
AND MONTH( SUBSTRING_INDEX( target_week,  '/', -1 ) ) = MONTH( CURRENT_DATE( ) )
```

to get all the target amounts of a particular month of a particular employee. The above gives me an output in phpMyAdmin and mySQL console. But when I use it with the php code it throws me an error like below,

```
( ! ) Warning: Division by zero in C:\wamp\www\kurl-on-fe\rest\init.php on line 75
```

and the php code is below and I have shown the line no 75 in the comment,

```
$q = $this->connection->prepare('SELECT * FROM targets WHERE emp_id_tar =61 AND MONTH( SUBSTRING_INDEX( target_week,  '/', 1 ) ) = MONTH( CURRENT_DATE( ) ) AND MONTH( SUBSTRING_INDEX( target_week,  '/', -1 ) ) = MONTH( CURRENT_DATE( ) )');

// above line is line number 75
$bo = 61;
$q->bind_param('i', $bo);
$q->execute();
$res = $q->get_result();
$temp = array();
while($row = $res->fetch_assoc()) {
    $temp[] = $row;
}
return json_encode($temp);
```

I'm really confused what and where I am doing wrong? Please help me to come out of this problem. And one more thing is I'm using `2013-10-20/2013-10-26` this structure for start and end of the week. So I used `substring_index()` method to get the dates separately.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

replace you single quotes with double quotes

`'/'` with `"/"`

```
$q = $this->connection->prepare('SELECT * FROM targets 
       WHERE emp_id_tar =61 AND 
       MONTH( SUBSTRING_INDEX( target_week,  "/", 1 ) ) = MONTH( CURRENT_DATE( ) ) 
       AND 
       MONTH( SUBSTRING_INDEX( target_week,  "/", -1 ) ) = MONTH( CURRENT_DATE( ) )');
```

Answer (score 1):

Try This

```
$q = $this->connection->prepare("SELECT * FROM targets 
WHERE emp_id_tar =61 AND MONTH( SUBSTRING_INDEX( target_week,  '/', 1 ) ) = MONTH( CURRENT_DATE( ) ) AND MONTH( SUBSTRING_INDEX( target_week,  '/', -1 ) ) = MONTH( CURRENT_DATE( ) )");
```